# Bootstrap grid - 4 columns - Uneven text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4

I have a four column grid in my page with each column containing a logo, an `<h2>` and a `<p>`.

How do I horizontally align the paragraphs so that they match? When the h2 line requires a second line, it pushes down the paragraph. I want there to be room for the h2 to take up the second line without affecting the paragraphs.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
    
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h2>SEO Copywriting</h2>
                    <p>Get more eyes on your work.</p>
                </div><!-- /col -->
    
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h2>Video Scripts</h2>
                    <p>When words aren’t enough.</p>
                </div><!-- /col -->
    
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h2>Blog Entries</h2>
                    <p>Pick a subject, any subject.</p>
                </div><!-- /col -->
    
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h2>Copy Editing & Proofreading</h2>
                    <p>Take your work that extra mile.</p>
                </div><!-- /col -->
    
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </section><!-- /services -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the solution is a little bit more complex and might not seem immediately obvious.

First, you need to split up the elements into different columns i.e. the paragraphs must go into separate columns. And we need to use the `md` breakpoint for columns because `sm` is too small in this case.

Next, you have to use the `order` classes to reorder the columns based on the screen size.

So, the first four columns get the classes `order-1`, `order-2`, `order-3` and `order-4` respectively and that means they will always keep that order at all breakpoints.

The paragraph columns that are located underneath in the HTML will also get those same order classes first. But additionally, the paragraph columns also get the `order-md-5` class which effectively pushes all paragraph down for screens that are medium (md) or larger.

Here's the full, working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page for testing):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">

            <div class="col-md-3 order-1">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h2>SEO Copywriting</h2>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-2">
                <i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h2>Video Scripts</h2>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-3">
                <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h2>Blog Entries</h2>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-4">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h2>Copy Editing &amp; Proofreading</h2>
            </div><!-- /col -->
            
            <div class="col-md-3 order-1 order-md-5">
                <p>Get more eyes on your work.</p>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-2 order-md-5">
                <p>When words aren’t enough.</p>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-3 order-md-5">
                <p>Pick a subject, any subject.</p>
            </div><!-- /col -->

            <div class="col-md-3 order-4 order-md-5">
                <p>Take your work that extra mile. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet added text for testing.</p>
            </div><!-- /col -->
            
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</section><!-- /services -->
```

Comment: Of course, the `sm` breakpoint is too small in your case. You probably should do the `md` or even the `lg` breakpoint for the columns. OR you should reduce the font size for smaller screens.

Comment: That doesn't work because the content is different sizes. The "& Proofreading" ends up on a different line which pushes the < p > do a lower line that the other paragraphs.

Comment: You wanted to vertically align the items, didn't you? The code achieves exactly that. And I agree that other adjustments are needed but that wasn't the question.

Comment: How do I vertically align each row of text **so that they match**?

Comment: So, I can add media queries to size it down as the screen gets smaller? Or use an adjustable font size?

It seems that either way that line of text will push everything down.

Comment: Well, maybe you should specify exactly what do you mean by "row of text"? What text? Only the h2 elements? Or only the `p` elements? You need to be a little more precise.

Comment: I tried putting it on different grid rows, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Ok. I want the logos to be lined up. I want the h2 elements to be lined up. And the paragraph elements lined up. To one another. I don't want it to look sloppy.

Comment: So, you want the h2 elements to be vertically aligned with each other, correct? Independently from the other elements?

Comment: What you want it to vertically align each of the 3 types of elements with each other: icons, h2 elements and the `p` elements. Correct?

Comment: But from the `md` breakpoint down, they should all stack up appropriately, right?

Comment: Most importantly I want all the paragraphs to be on one horizontal line.

I don't understand your use of the word "breakpoint".

Comment: So sorry. How dumb of me. I keep saying vertical when I mean horizontal.

Comment: On "one horizontal line" is very imprecise/unclear. Should each paragraph **start** on the same line (no matter how long the paragraph is) or should each paragraph be vertically center aligned?

Comment: When you make the screen smaller right now, all `h2` elements *start* on the same line. Do you agree? So, there's no problem with the h2 elements, right?

Comment: I described the problem. The h2s are fine. They start in the same place. The paragraphs get pushed down a line when the h2 doesn't fit. It's ugly.

Comment: Alright, now, that the requirements are clear, I updated my answer and code snippet. Check it out.

Comment: That answer is perfect. Thank you for pushing me to explain. Sorry, I wasn't clear right off the bat.